# Use JavaScript to find innerHTML text and return parent tag ID

Tags: javascript, html, dom

With JavaScript, one often want to use the e.g. getElementById() function to search for a HTML-tag with a specific ID and return it's innerHTML values.

However, is it possible to achieve the opposite?

```
<tag1 id="myID1">
    <tag2 id="myID2">
        <tag3>myText</tag3>
    </tag2>
</tag1>
```

I want to create a function which is looking for the first appearance of "myText" as a innerHTML text and returning it's upper most parent tag id. In this case, if I search for "myText", I expect to return "myID1". How can JavaScript achieve that?

Comment: Start by iterating through all the elements in a loop, checking innerhtml.  Then traverse through found element's parents until you find the one you want.

Comment: This might also help get you started - https://richard2001.blogspot.com/2010/02/select-elements-by-innerhtml-with.html

Comment: @CertainPerformance OP is asking if a method exists and for guidance.  I don't think they need to do more than make the effort to post the question.

Comment: No such built-in method exists, thus he should start by attempting to write such a function (rather than asking SO to figure it all out for him)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To scan through the children of an html element you could use a recursive function something like:

```
function findInnerHTMLMatch(s,e){
  if (e.innerHTML===s) return e;
  for (let n=0;n<e.children.length;n++){
    const rtn=findInnerHTMLMatch(s,e.children[n]);
    if (rtn) return rtn;
  }
}
```

then if you want to find on the whole page just call `findInnerHTMLMatch('myText',document.body)`.

This will return the DOM element containing exactly and only the text you specify.

After that I find your requirements unclear.  If you are seeking the ultimate parent element then, logically, you will end up with the `<html>` element every time.  So, are you after the top element with an `id` defined?  If not what else and, perhaps most importantly as this will help clarify things, why?

---

Just because I enjoy thinking about these things... If you want to do it without recursion, a stack works well and is possibly more elegent:

```
function findInnerHTMLMatch(s,e){
  const stack=[e];
  while (stack.length){
    const el=stack.pop();
    if (el.innerHTML===s) return el;
    stack.push(...el.children);
  }
}
```

Comment: Your solution needed some fixes in order to be compatible with Internet Explorer (var instead of const and let) - but it  works!